# Bootstrap - Navbar not changing on orientation change

Tags: jquery, mobile, twitter-bootstrap-3

When I use "navbar-fixed-top" the orientation change event would trigger a "resize" of the navbar, on a mobile device (a resize event on a desktop does correctly trigger a resize of the navbar). On the right side of the navbar I have a collapsible navbar-toggle, which opens/closes the main menu: when changing orientation from landscape to portrait, the menu button is no more visible.

This only happens on Android mobiles and not in Iphone.

Comment: what exactly you want to achieve by handling resize event on mobile ?

Comment: I need the menu to be present even when the mobile's orientation is changed. The menu bar is present in portrait view and it is not present in landscape view.

Comment: Have you used the `Reponsive utility classes` or `@media` like its mentioned here http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#responsive or are you changing the navbar orientation based on the screen re-size event ?

Comment: I have used its own class and not by my own code. Can you check the following link http://dawnaqua.in/demo/mukam